# Sum based on different breakdowns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have these two tables with respective mappings.

```
Food     | Price
=====================
Apple    | 6
Broccoli | 2
Orange   | 4
Mangoes  | 4
Spinach  | 3
Chicken  | 9
Pork     | 3  

Type       | Food
=====================
Vegetable  | Broccoli
Vegetable  | Spinach
Fruit      | Apple
Fruit      | Mango
Fruit      | Orange
Meat       | Chicken
Meat       | Pork
```

Now I need another table where I bucket these types of Food based on the sum of their prices

So

```
Type        | Sum of Price
==========================
Vegetable   | 5
Fruit       | 14
Meat        | 12
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay to add one extra helper column (it can be very last column), you can achieve this very easily.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using index method or vlookup, you can add a column Type. Now, the data is tabular and a good candidate for Pivot Tables. You can now select the complete range and go to Insert -> Pivot Table. Drag Type to Row Labels, and Price to Values Column, and there you go :)